# nuget push gives internal server error while using CIFS share

Tags: nuget

My nuget push works fine when I use a local drive for storing packages. However, if I mount a CIFS share as a drive and folder (`F:\nuget_repo`), the nuget push command fails with 
`The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error..`

When I look at Event Viewer Windows application logs, I see a warning

`DOMAIN\nuget_account 
DirectoryNotFoundException 
Could not find a part of the path 'F:\nuget_repo'.`

`DOMAIN|nuget_account` is the account I use to connect to my `CIFS` share on windows host and it has full `R/W` access to the share.

So I am guessing there is some permissions issue I am not able to recognize.

Has anybody used this setup before and got it working?

Any assistance/suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's probably not a matter of permissions but of sessions. You're mapping the drive in your user session, and the upload is probably being performed by a service in a different session - which doesn't contain your drive mappings. Try using the UNC path.

Comment: That seems to be logical, but I updated my web.config to use UNC path as \\nas_host\nas_share_name\drive...republished my VS solution. Did an IIS reset/restart. The error is same and warning still points F:\nuget_repo. Did I miss a step or Is there some kind of cache that I am missing? Thanks